# What training scheme keras.fit use

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I am training various Autoencoder structures in keras+tensorflow for my master thesis on anomaly detection and during my literature research on how to train the autoencoder structures, I found various training schemes for Autoencoders including, [Layerwise pretraining](https://machinelearningmastery.com/greedy-layer-wise-pretraining-tutorial/) and [Joint training](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.1380.pdf). However, I have not been able to find any literature on how Keras.fit() handles the training process. Can anyone point me to any useful links?

Comment: It is just stochastic gradient descent, nothing fancy.

Comment: I am not sure if you understand my question then, or if I do not understand your answer. 
To my knowledge, gradient descent is an optimization technique for finding the minimum of the objective function given the constraints. Both Layerwise pretraining and Joint training uses gradient descent to optimize their objective function. 
I guess the appropriate question is: "how does Keras build the objective function?"

Comment: What I mean is that Keras does not do anything like layer pretraining or joint training, those are techniques implemented on top of gradient descent.